# Returning a pointer in golang

Tags: pointers, go

Im a beginner here at `go` but i have a question:

I have the following code:

```
package lab

import (
 "fmt"
 "math"
)

type Circle struct {
  x float64
  y float64
  r float64
}

func (c *Circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.r * c.r
}

func StructCode() {
    c := Circle{1,2,5}
    fmt.Println("struct addr",c)
    fmt.Println("Circle",c.area())
}
```

My question is, the `Circle area function` takes a `Circle Pointer` and returns the area. Based on this. **why when i print the struct it doesnt show a memory address, but shows `&{1 2 5}` instead** . It takes a pointer for the area function but the `c circle` isn't printing as a pointer (in which i imagine it would have printed a memory address being a `circle pointer`)

**UPDATE**

Unless possibly `&{1 2 5}` is actually the reference?

**SECOND UPDATE**

I was able to get it doing this:

```
c := Circle{1,2,5}
p := &c
fmt.Printf("%p",p)

// returns 0xc042052340
```

However my question now is, why can I pass `c.area()` instead of `p.area()` as area function of circle requires a pointer:

Comment: This is simply the default behaviour of the `fmt` package. If you use a custom formatting string, you can have it always print the pointer (`%p`).

Comment: @TimCooper can you make a answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we call a pointer receiver method with value as receiver. Go interprets the function call `c.area()` as `(&c).area()`. This convenience is provided by go itself. 
In [Golang](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) spec it is function call is described as

> A method call **x.m()** is valid if the method set of (the type of) x
>   contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list
>   of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, **x.m()** is
>   shorthand for **(&x).m()**